# Why is my dependency injection not working in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Why my Dependency Injection for chart.js does not work? Details below:

Snippet from my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="angularApp">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Wall</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <form>
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Write on the wall"></textarea>
                      </div>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                  </div>

                  <div ng-controller="wallPosts">
                    <div class="panel panel-default post" ng-repeat="post in posts">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <a class="post-avatar thumbnail" href="profile.html"><div class="text-center">DevUser1</div></a>
                          </div><!-- col-sm-2 end -->
                          <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <p>test</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-7">
                            <div class="bubble">
                              <div class="pointer">
                                <p>test</p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="pointer-border"></div>
                            </div><!-- buddle end -->
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie" chart-data="data" chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options">
                            </canvas> 
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div><!-- col-md-8 end -->
          </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/angular/angularApp.js"></script> 
    <script src="/jsLib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jsLib/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Angular Controller File:

```
var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp', ['chart.js']);

angularApp.controller('wallPosts', ['$scope', 'chart.js', function($scope){

    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];

}]);
```

The error I am getting is this:

> Error: Chart.js library needs to included, see

http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

The thing is, I seem to have done exactly what is required in the link and it's still not working.

If you see what I am doing wrong here, please let me know. Pulling my hair out on this for most of the day.

Thanks,
Shayan

Comment: I don't see anything in the documentation about being able to inject chart.js into a controller?

Comment: Yeah everyone here is saying the same thing. Pretty embarrassing if you ask me haha. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include angular-chart.min.js and Chart.min.js before angularApp.js in your html.

And there is no need to include chart.js in controller parameters.

```
angularApp.controller('wallPosts', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];

}]);
```

Comment: That did the trick mate! How I didn't see the mistake is beyond me. Thanks so much for this!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with the chart.js you have injected in the controller . remove it from the controller injection then try it .

Comment: That did it mate. Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13005764)

Comment: @theblindprophet I was not allowed to comment below the post as my reputation was less than 50 , So I write the comment here and it do solve the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Your are injecting chart.js in your controller is not correct, please check the below code..
Eg:

```
 angularApp.controller('wallPosts', function($scope){

    $scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
    $scope.data = [300, 500, 100];

}]);
```

For more understanding : http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/